# Using Expressions to get a Get Acessor of a property

Tags: c#, api, reflection, lambda, expression

I want to get the Get Acessor of a Property (`PropertyInfo`) and compile it to a `Func<object,object>`. The declaring type is only known at runtime.

My current code is:

```
public Func<Object, Object> CompilePropGetter(PropertyInfo info)
{
    MethodInfo getter = info.GetGetMethod();

    ParameterExpression instance = Expression.Parameter(info.DeclaringType, info.DeclaringType.Name);

    MethodCallExpression setterCall = Expression.Call(instance, getter);

    Expression getvalueExp = Expression.Lambda(setterCall, instance);


    Expression<Func<object, object>> GetPropertyValue = (Expression<Func<object, object>>)getvalueExp;
    return GetPropertyValue.Compile();

}
```

Unfortunately, I have to put `<Object,Object>` as generic parameters, because sometimes I will get the properties of a `Type`, like `typeof(T).GetProperties()[0].GetProperties()`, where the first GetProperties()[] returns a custom-type object, and I have to reflect it.

When I run the code above, I get this error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[**CustomType**,**OtherCustomType**]]' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[System.Object,System.Object]]'.
```

So, what can I do to return a `Func<Object,Object>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add casts to the expected type and from the return type using `Expression.Convert`:

```
public static Func<Object, Object> CompilePropGetter(PropertyInfo info)
{
    ParameterExpression instance = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
    var propExpr = Expression.Property(Expression.Convert(instance, info.DeclaringType), info);
    var castExpr = Expression.Convert(propExpr, typeof(object));
    var body = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(castExpr, instance);
    return body.Compile();
}
```